# ¿Como implementar de manera correcta Comments Social Plugin de Facebook?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

estoy implementando comentarios en en mi sitio web y ya funcionan, los comentarios si los enlaza con mi sitio web, PERO no me permite utilizar la función: **[ ] También compartir en Facebook**. El codigo que utilice es el oficial de Facebook es el siguiente:

```
    <script>(function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id))
                return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/es_LA/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=536586936693499&autoLogAppEvents=1';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
```

HTML

url = pagina en donde pusimos los comentarios.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<%=url%>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

META

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{mi_id}"/>
```

ERROR

Me envía un error en el dashboard del navegador, es el siguiente:

```
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments/async/createComment/1918748084862644/?av=100000899565079&dpr=1.5 500 ()
```